# C# JsonProperty with "formattable" name

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, data-annotations, json-deserialization

I have a model annotated this way:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[JsonProperty("extension_{0}_name")]
public string name {get; set;}
```

This data is being retrieved by a query to an Azure domain, and via Postman I can see the actual property being filled in a specific field:

```
{
     "extension_129af129412_name":"John",
     ...
}
```

where `129af129412` matches a `AzurePropertyExtensionId` property, defined in my Web.Config as:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AzurePropertyExtensionId" value="129af129412" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
</appSettings>
```

However, when I try to deserialize the object with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>` the field is not retrieved. I suspect this is because the binding is made on a field `name_{0}_property` instead of `name_129af129412_property`.

I guess there is something going wrong with the `xdt:Transform` attribute of the Web.Config: whoever wrote it assumed that the `JsonProperty` name would be rewritten correctly, but this is not the case. Once serialized with `JsonConvert`, the field is serialized as `extension_{0}_name`. What is going wrong here?

Side note: there is a funny behaviour with Azure in that we are sending to Azure the serialized model with the `{0}` placeholder in place, and the field is saved on Azure anyway. So, it seems that while we on the WebServer are unable to deserialize the field because of the mismatch between field names, Azure is capable of overcoming this problem by itself. I would be interested in understanding how this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was a `ContractResolver` instance responsible for the conversion of `JsonProperty` field names that was not being passed as part of the `JsonSerializerSettings`. Once added the resolver instance to the (de) serialization steps, the field was successfully retrieved.